# Symfony 5 Mailer send mail with profile picture

Tags: symfony, smtp, mailer, symfony5

so i'm trying to send emails from symfony using my provider's smtp server.

everything is working just good. but now what i'm trying to do is to show my profile picture as avatar on the send email (instead of that avatar)

[image: email avatar example]

i'm using the basic mailer sendEMail() function :

```
$message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
        ->setFrom('send@example.com')
        ->setTo('recipient@example.com')
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                // templates/emails/registration.html.twig
                'emails/registration.html.twig',
                ['name' => $name]
            ),
            'text/html'
        );

        // you can remove the following code if you don't define a text version for your emails
       

    $mailer->send($message);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, from where is this avatar image? If is from gmail or outlook? If yes you can change it in your personal account and i can't think a way to change it from just a email. I don't think is allowed to change someone else personal profile image just because you send them a email, this will be security breach.

Comment: hi, thanku for responding. the avatar that i want to show is mine ... i'm using an email from domaine and i have an avatar on it .. but when i send email to someone else, it doesn't appear.

Comment: In what client,site or application are you browse your emails?

Comment: I need the same thing. Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible. I think this image is only shown in Gmail, if the email is sent through their SMTP service (either personal Gmail or G Suite). Basically, it's something within their system only. Please, correct me, if I am wrong, I would love to be able to do this.